# Why one outlet on a branch suddenly shows lower voltage?

Tags: receptacle, voltage, canada

I have a branch with few outlets and ligths on it, and one outlet developed a problem overnight, in the sense that whatever was plugged into it was energized last night, but was not in the morning. The breaker did not trip.

While troubleshooting I found that the voltage between hot and neutral on that outlet is about 90V, while the voltage between hot and ground is 110V, as expected. I opened up a couple of other outlets, one on the same branch, another on a different branch, and both show 110V between hot and neutral.

I replaced the problematic outlet but it did not help.

What would be my next steps in troubleshooting/fixing it, apart from calling a professional?

Comment: You probably have a loose connection on the outlet before the problem one.  I would guess the neutral is the loose one but tighten all the others to the correct torque values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work backwards through all other receptacles and other junction boxes (e.g., sometimes in switch boxes or light fixture boxes, and sometimes boxes that are *only* for connecting things) towards the circuit breaker. There is most likely a loose connection somewhere. Any type of connection can be loose, or just so little metal connecting that it functions like a loose connection.

- Backstabs - These are the worst. If you find any, move them to screw terminals.
- Screw terminals - Should loop around clockwise - otherwise tightening pushes the wire out. Should see very little copper *not* under the screws. Should not see *any* insulation under the screws.
- Wire nuts - Do a pull test - if any wire comes out then redo the connection (replacing the wire nut is preferred, but sometimes they can be reused successfully). If a wire nut is loose - you can twist it without the wires turning with it - then redo the connection. If a wire nut is cracked, replace it. If any copper is showing on the wires (except for ground wires, of course), redo the connection.

Comment: Freshly bought receptacle tester confirmed "open neutral". Now I'll just have to find where...

Comment: A receptacle tester doesn't truly "know" open neutral. The "open neutral" light sequence means "there is sufficient voltage between hot and ground to light up one light" + "there is insufficient voltage between hot and neutral to light up that light" + "there is insufficient voltage between neutral and ground to light up that light". Which you basically already knew from "90V between hot and neutral".

Answer (score 0):

Just for the closure, it was indeed a loose neutral in a wire nut in one of the junction boxes on the way to the problematic receptacle. Replaced nuts with WAGOs and all is well now.